# Using iphone accelerometer to count the number of spins when tossed in the air

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

I would like to have a program that build a program that uses the accelerometer to count the number of time an iphone spins (either on a table top or when tossed in the air )  any suggestions?

Comment: Please dont encourage people to toss their iPhones!

Comment: No, please do! (I own Apple stock and I assume that enough people with broken phones would go and buy a new one.)

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone 4 may be able to do this, as it has gyroscopes that are not affected by acceleration, but when you spin a device with an accelerometer the accelerometer will just report that it seems like there's a large acceleration pointing on a vector from the center of rotation straight out.

Answer (score 1):

You throw your iPhone in the air?

Just a heads up if you're planning on putting this on the App Store - Apple rejected/removed an app that measured the speed an iPhone fell at while being dropped. The reason they gave was because it would encourage users to do things with their iPhone that would potentially damage it. Your app would likely befall the same fate.

Comment: maybe, but I think I have a way around that. If i can figure out how to program it. At the very least they would not reject spinning on a desk like a top